# Yoast SEO Wordpress plugin - how to access the $schema array from the outside

Tags: php, wordpress, schema, yoast

I have fiddled around with actions and filters and the like in a previous version of the Yoast plugin but now I can see that the PHP coding style has radically changed and I'm a bit lost. I'm more familiar with the old-school coding style.

I would like to grab the $schema array before it is output and be able to add stuff into it. I have seen that there are many specific classes in the Yoast plugin to manipulate the schema pieces but I can't make head or tail of it.

The $schema array is set up in the file \wordpress-seo\src\presenters\schema-presenter.php and returned from there, presumably to a higher function to be output, and it seems that this is probably the simplest place to add to the data.

So basically I would like to be able to hook into that function from any template piece and insert an array block before it's returned.

I have looked at the documentation at Yoast developer but I'm not really any the wiser!

Does anyone have any experience of doing this ?

Thanks :)

Comment: I'm pretty certain you want to look into the [`Schema_Generator`](https://github.com/Yoast/wordpress-seo/blob/master/src/generators/schema-generator.php) class. In there you'll find a bunch of filters that start with `wpseo_schema_` that allow you to tweak things. There's even a filter called `wpseo_schema_graph_pieces` that will allow you to write a custom class to have your own schema added.

Comment: Ok thanks, i'll have a look at that. And maybe update my coding knowledge too!